# Does sessionAffinity over ClientIP works with UDP protocol on Kubernetes setup?

Tags: kubernetes, udp, openshift, kubernetes-helm

lets say, we have two independent Kubernetes clusters `Cluster 1 & Cluster 2` , Each of them has two replicas of same application Pod. Like
`Cluster 1 : Pod A & Pod B`
`Cluster 2 : Pod C & Pod D`
Application code in Pod A(client) wants to connect to any Pod running in cluster 2 via NodePort/Loadbalancer service over UDP protocol to send messages. The only requirement is, to maintain affinity so that all messages from Pod A should go to any one pod only (either Pod C or Pod D). Since, UDP is a connectionless protocol, my concern is around the session Affinity based on ClientIP. Should setting the sessionAffinity as client IP solve my issue ?

Answer (score 3):

> Since, UDP is a connectionless protocol, my concern is around the session Affinity based on ClientIP. Should setting the sessionAffinity as client IP solve my issue ?

`sessionAffinity` keeps each session based on sourceIP regardless of the protocols at the same cluster. But it does not mean your real session is kept as you expected on your env across your whole access path journey.
**In other words, just only using sessionAffinity does not ensure keeping whole session on your access paths.**

For example, Pod A outbound IP is translated as running node IP(SNAT) if you does not use egress IP solutions for the Pod A.
It also depends your NodePort and LoadBalancer Service config about source IP in cluster 2. Refer [Using Source IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/) for more details.

So you should consider how to keep session safely while accessing each other between other clusters. Personally I think you had better consider application layer(7Layer) sticky session for keeping the session, not sessionAffinity of the service.

Comment: Hi @Daein, thanks for the answer. actually, in my case, first connection from POD A to POD C is on TCP and POD C tells in response, the UDP port where POD A needs to initiate other new connection. Here, requirement is, the POD at server side, which served the TCP request, that should only receive the UDP request as well. I am trying this scenario, but subsequent UDP requests falls in other POD at server side.  I see no effect of sessionAffinity at ClientIP.

Comment: @Nish Unfortunately I don't think the session which is across TCP and UDP is kept using sessionAffinity. That is implemented as iptables rules and it's basically enforce the rule either tcp or udp, not mixed protocols one by one a point in time.

Comment: ohh! Thats really unfortunate! Are you aware of any other workaround to handle this kind of case?

Comment: @Nish It's a unusual use case, so how about eliminate the dependency of a specific pod on your application ? Or you can consider to keep  one pod at the backend using each deployment.